# How element can become an engine?

Tags: frameworks

When I research one Java framework(OFBiz,...), i think it's similar to other languages. I usually read some elements are called as engine(widget engine, data engine,...). My question is what are standards to call one element as `engine`?

My example is OFBiz framework, it has some engines: widget engine, data engine.

Comment: It is the framework authors' opinions on what should be called an engine. So it is not programming language specific. I removed both Java and C# tags, as they are irrelevant. Neither Microsoft (for C#) nor Oracle (for Java) publishes any documentation on how you should name a class so you should assume that the rule of thumb is "be smart".

Answer (score 2):

In my mind this is not a question which can be answered in one correct way.

I personally agree with the definition in the wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_%28computer_science%29 (IMHO better description in german: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine)

An engine in computer science is an independent part of an application. It is responsible for complex computation or simulations. Often an engine is running in the background, without being controlled by or being dependent of an user.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but this answer is not clear!